# Difference between dm_exec_sql_text vs dm_exec_input_buffer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As per Microsoft docs, `dm_exec_sql_text` returns the text of the SQL batch that is identified by the specified sql_handle while `dm_exec_input_buffer` returns information about statements submitted to an instance of SQL Server.

I used `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` for getting the last executed SQL. But it seems both `dm_exec_sql_text` and `dm_exec_input_buffer` are replacement `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`. If this is the case then what is the main difference between them? When should we use one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` represents only the batch or RPC call that began the request, in other words the command initiated by the client directly, not any later procedures or triggers called. As noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), you can only pass a `session_id` and `request_id`. This is the equivalent of `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` as you have noted.

Meanwhile, [`sys.dm_exec_sql_text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can be passed an `sql_handle` or a `plan_handle`, which can be got from various places, not least from `sys.dm_exec_requests`, which means that you can get the text of the *currently* executing statement, not just the initial batch.